# Sending data to server side from client side - INVALID JSON PRIMITIVE: location

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

At the moment, I have a user that is creating a lot of points on an ajax bing map. When the user presses 'submit' button, I would like to get all the locations stored in map.entities, I build a string with xml format, and I would like to save it in my DB:

```
<locations> <location><lat><lon>1.234</lon></lat></location>.....</locations>
```

, so after building my XML string, which is not a problem, I store it in variable locations and do:

```
$. ajax({ 
type: "POST",
url: "myPage.aspx/saveLocations"
data: {"xmlLoc: x"},
async: true,
cache: false,
success: alert ("success" + msg)
error: ....
```

But unfortunately it seems this is not the way to pass my data. This is the only time I get a success, but the msg is UNDEFINED!!!

If I write
    data: x, <-- the problem I would have here is that I get  A POTENTIALLY DANGEROUS REQUEST IS SENT FROM THE CLIENT

MY server side code:

```
[Web Method]
public static string saveLocations(string s)
{
    return s; //just for testing purposes
}
```

I'm not sure If I have to use json or something else, I'm quite a beginner so I have no idea from where to start! Thank you very much

---

Edit: I am trying another workaround, but I always get invalid json primitive error!!!

```
var locations = '{ "location" : [';
function createBoundary() {                        
            for (x = 0; x < map.entities.getLength(); x++) {
                var pin = map.entities.get(x);
                locations += '{ "latitude": "' + pin.getLocation().latitude +'", "longitude": "' + pin.getLocation().longitude + '"},';
            }
locations += ']}';
jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Profiles_Schedules.aspx/GetXmlLoc",
                data:  eval("(" + locations + ")"),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("Success " + msg.d);
                },
                error: function (x, e) {
                    alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: what happens if you set your data as data: {"s: 'x'"}

Comment: You can't write that, I get an unexpected tocken }

Answer (score 2):

Try adding datatype:

```
dataType: "json",
```

Also I think that your data should be "s" and not "xmlLoc", since that's what you're looking for in your action.

And try changing your Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public static string saveLocations(string s)
{
    return s; //just for testing purposes
}
```

Comment: I have syntax error I cannot even Resolve HttpPost, should I reference a particular assembly please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on the receiving end, but your data is not passed in a recognizable format.  `jQuery.ajax()` makes an [intelligent guess](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to the data format, but the quickest conversion for you would be to JSON:

```
data: '{"xmlLoc":"x"}'
```

The quotes are necessary for the proper JSON format.

Comment: maybe I'm not sure about this but is it a MUST to type "xmlLoc" on the left side of this code you showed  to me? Still I get an error, The call to server side failed

Comment: The left side should contain the key of the post variable and the right side should contain the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to the following:

```
data: {"s":"x"}
```

[Even on JSON's site](http://json.org/), you must format your key/value pairs with quotes if you want string to string. I would suggest naming your key the same as your parameter though.

Per [the MSDN on WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) I initially thought that this might not work via the WebMethodAttribute since it consumes SOAP calls. However, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625250/webmethod-response-format) is interesting in that it states that the JSON will be format into the appropriate SOAP format. Kind of nice :)

**However,** the above does make me feel even stronger that your json key needs to match your method signature's naming for the serializations to work

Comment: One of my problems is that I am building a json array dynamically! Can you please re - check my code?

Comment: @test I did re-check and it looks the same? Nothing dynamic that I can see.

Comment: sorry just posted it now ! I hope I can find the mistake :(

Comment: @test There is a lot wrong there. You are building an array for one, not a string. Your createBoundary method also appears to never be called. Just because you put it between the += does not mean it will get called in between there. I would try to just make the basic call as you originally posted to make sure your webmethod is working. After that, if you have problems with the jquery portion, you really should post that as a separate question as that is what it is

Comment: thank you my friend. I am calling the function from somewhere else within the script and the string is being built for sure! But I'm not sure if it is in the correct format. At the moment I am trying to build it as a string since I dont think its possible to build a json array dynamically!

Comment: @test I can tell you that you can build a json array dynamically. I have done it before...a while ago, but I can take a look at some old code once I have my personal pc in front of me.